# Creating a directional link to an agent in radius with a particular attribute value

Tags: netlogo

I'm creating a mating simulation whereby "male" agents select the youngest "women" in their immediate vicinity (no offense!). Unfortunately it's throwing an error at the line `create-mtf-to min-one-of women [age] in-radius 1`. How can I create a directional link to the youngest "woman" agent in a radius 1 around the male agent who is searching?

```
to mate-with-women
  if any? women in-radius 1 [
    create-mtf-to min-one-of women [age] in-radius 1
    ask mtfs [set color blue]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a little easier if you told us what the error message says and which line. However, I think this will fix it:

```
to mate-with-women
  if any? women in-radius 1 [
    create-mtf-to min-one-of women in-radius 1 [age]
    ask mtfs [set color blue]
  ]
end
```

The agentset that you want to take the youngest from is `women in-radius 1`. If that doesn't work, try putting brackets (of the type '()') around `women in-radius 1`

As you test the agentset for members anyway so need to construct twice, another approach is:

```
to mate-with-women
  let potential-mates women in-radius 1
  if any? potential-mates [
    create-mtf-to min-one-of potential-mates [age]
    ask mtfs [set color blue]
  ]
end
```

This cleans up the syntax and may improve efficiency.

Comment: This worked amazingly. Thank you. I'm looking at how scale affects inter-agent investment strategies between agents with diametric profit maximization strategies.

Comment: Happy to help. It's bad form to change other parts of the code in a SO answer because it hides what the fix was, but I think you probably want `create-mtf-to min-one-of potential-mates [age] [set color blue]` rather than `create-mtf-to min-one-of potential-mates [age]  ask mtfs [set color blue]`. The way you have it will work, but every mtf link is set to blue every time the `if` is satisfied. This change will mean that the new mtf will be set to blue as it is created.

Comment: Gotcha! That would be a lot more efficient. Cheers.